# Is every weighted shift on $\ell^2$ unitarily equivalent to a weighted shift with positive weights?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Consider $\mathbf t = \{t_n\}_{n=1}^\infty \subset \Bbb C$, and define the left weighted shift operator $W_{\mathbf t}: \ell^2 \to \ell^2$ by $$W_{\mathbf t}(x_1,x_2,\ldots) = (t_1x_2,t_2x_3,\ldots)$$
Is $W_{\mathbf t}$ unitarily equivalent to some left weighted shift $W_{\mathbf p}$ where $\mathbf p = \{p_n\}_{n=1}^\infty \subset \Bbb R_{>0}$? The notation $\Bbb R_{>0}$ is used for positive real numbers.

Firstly, I wrote $t_j = r_j e^{i\theta_j}$ for every $j\ge 1$, i.e., converted to polar coordinates. My natural guess is that $W_{\mathbf t}$ and $W_{\mathbf r}$ should be unitarily equivalent, where $\mathbf r = \{r_n\}_{n=1}^\infty \subset \Bbb R_{\ge 0}$. The $r_j$'s can be zero, so even after establishing this equivalence, we must find an appropriate candidate for $\mathbf p$.

Thanks for any help! I'd appreciate hints or solutions.

Answer (score 1):

There is no unitary equivalence in general, if you require the weights $p$ to be positive. If $p_j>0$ for all $j$, then $\dim\ker W_p=1$, while if $m$ is the number of $j$ such that $r_j=0$, then $\dim\ker W_t=1+m$. So a necessary condition for $W_p$ and $W_t$ to be unitarily equivalent is that $m=0$.

If you only require the weights to be non-negative, the unitary you need is
$$\tag1
U(x_1,x_2,\ldots)=(x_1,e^{1+i\theta_1}x_2,e^{i (1+\theta_1+\theta_2)}x_3,\ldots).
$$
This is easy to address by using matrix units. You have, using the matrix units coming from the canonical basis,
$$
W=\sum_kt_kE_{k,k+1}.
$$
If you postulate that
$$
U=\sum_k e^{i \gamma_k}\,E_{kk},
$$
then
$$
UWU^*=\sum_{k,h,j} r_ke^{i \theta_k}e^{i \gamma_j}e^{-i \gamma_h}\,E_{jj}E_{k,k+1}E_{hh}=\sum_kr_ke^{i (\theta_k+\gamma_k-\gamma_{k+1})}\,E_{k,k+1}.
$$
Hence we need the recursion $$\theta_k+\gamma_k-\gamma_{k+1}=0,$$ and we get $(1)$.

Comment: What do you mean by matrix units? I haven't seen this terminology before, and I don't know what the $E_{i,j}$'s are.

Comment: $E_{kj}$ is the rank-one operator that sends $e_j$ to $e_k$.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure why the recursion $\theta_k+\gamma_k-\gamma_{k+1}=0$ will be satisfied. The $\gamma_k$'s depend on $U$, and $U$ is chosen to be the operator you mention in the first display. It is not clear why the $\gamma_k$'s should satisfy the said recursion. Besides, some of the $r_k$'s may be $0$, so this does not solve the problem fully, even if it is correct. We require an operator with **positive** weights, i.e., zero weights are *not allowed.*

Comment: I mistyped the coefficients in $(1)$. If you write $$\gamma_{k+1}=\gamma_k+\theta_k$$ you can take $\gamma_1=1$ and then $$\gamma_{k+1}=1+\theta_1+\cdots+\theta_k.$$ As for the condition that the coefficients are positive, if you enforce it the problem becomes completely trivial with a negative answer; as for example you are allowing $W_t=0$. In fact,  if even one $r_k$ is zero there is no unitary equivalence with an operator with all positive weights.